# MODX dynamic generate image-paths

Tags: image, path, modx

i am searching for a solid solution,
to get img-paths for all images inside a ressource folder.
To easy fill in path information to a fullscreen background slider.

Anyone out there keen on Modx or Modx-Plugins?

thx sven

Answer (score 0):

I would create an image TV and use this jquery plugin, is rock-solid http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

check this example: http://s401229343.mialojamiento.es/es/home